# Create selector with id from ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, server, jquery-selectors

I am reciving id and a link from my ajax call. I have to use id to find my tr, and then show the link in the td with class .center-xs

her is my HTML code:

...

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>My Link</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr id="abc">
        <td>Jons</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Football</td>
        <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="def">
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Football</td>
        <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ghi">
        <td>Harry</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>Football</td>
        <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

...

Her is my Ajex call:

...

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/url/Letter',
            type: 'post',
            cache: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({ letter: data }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {
            $('#' + res.Id + '').closest(".center-xs").html('<a href="' + res.Link + '">Open link</a>');


            }
        });
```

...

Comment: If in doubt, review the document - [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes *up* the document tree - you want [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to look at the children of the `tr`.

Comment: FYI `+ ''` is useless

Answer (score 0):

It is `.find`(go down the DOM tree), not `.closest` (go up the DOM tree)

And your quotes are a little weird - template literals are easier to use/read

```js
const res = { Id : "def", Link:"https://google.com" };
$(`#${res.Id}`).find(".center-xs").html(`<a href="${res.Link}">Open link</a>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sport</th>
      <th>My Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="abc">
      <td>Jons</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Football</td>
      <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="def">
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Football</td>
      <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ghi">
      <td>Harry</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Football</td>
      <td class="center-xs"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please reload the page. It works here. So perhaps you implemented it wrong or posted data not matching your real data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not working :( There are still no link to click on.

I am using this query inside ajax call, Can that have an effect?

Comment: No. the code works if you have the `res.Id` and the `res.Link` spelled correctly and that the content of res.Id is found in the page, spelled like that